# How to force to implement all fields a C# object?

Tags: c#, object, inheritance, interface, abstract-class

I have this object on a class library (project "A" that I want to use in my multiple projects ("B" and "C"):

```cs
public class Notification : INotification
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public int Type { get; set; }

    public IList<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class Message: IMessage
{
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public string Culture { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public interface INotification
{
    string Id { get; set; }

    int Type { get; set; }

    IList<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}
```

Now If I want to create this object on my project "B" I need to do the flowing:

```cs
static void Main()
{
    Notification notification = new Notification()
    {
        Id = "someId",
        Type = 1,
        Messages = new List<Message>()
        {
            new Message()
            {
                Culture = "en-US",
                Key = "Some key",
                Value = "Some value"
            }
        }
    };

    Console.WriteLine(notification.Id);
}
```

The problem is, since all fields are need to be `Required` if I don't initialize for example the "Type" no error is shown. What I want is that my project "B" implement the "Notification" object like I want, with all required fields, so my message can not be created without the "Type".
How can I do this? Do I need to create an abstraction?

Comment: this is not a matter of inheritance, you could simply make all fields private and do the logic in the constructor to ensure all properties are set.

Comment: Is this .NET or .NET Core?

Comment: What exactly do you expect the `[Required]` attribute to do?

Comment: I think you should convert your interfaces to abstract classes

Comment: @nAviD .net Core

Comment: @JohnWu maybe I'm doing it wrong, but I expect that this attribute is required to be set when object is instantiated.

Comment: Create a separated class library (assembly) with `Notification` class; add reference to this assembly fro projects `A`, `B` and `C`

Comment: @Shehab an then the project "B" and "C" will implement it?

Comment: The Required Attribute is to indicate something then creating an SQL-Database. C# itself has no idea or flag of anything required. So for you, this attribute does just nothing. There is nobody operating in background and "shows you an error".

Comment: Are you allowed to modify project "A" ?

Comment: @Fildor yes, and then use it across multiple projects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In c#, the way to require field initialization is to provide them as constructor arguments.

```
public class Notification : INotification
{
    public Notification(string id, int type, IList<Message> messages)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Type = type;
        this.Messages = messages;
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }

    public int Type { get; set; }

    public IList<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}
```

Without a default constructor, it is now impossible to construct a Notification without specifying a Type. This is enforced at compile-time, not run-time.

If you want null checks, you will have to add them yourself as part of the constructor logic. You can also add a range check for the `int` or other validation.

Note: `Type` is a terrible name for a variable.

Comment: Since `id` could still be `null` you might want to consider adding `this.id = id ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(id));`. `Messages` _could_ be set to an empty list if null, but that would depend on the requirements.

Comment: So with this, I need to implement all the fields in my other projects. And yes, I will change the ```Type``` to ```NotificationType```. Thank you for your help!